# How to select right amount of buttons

Tags: javascript, css, button

I have a textbox and a set of buttons below the text box. What is suppose to happen is that a user fills in a number in the text box and that number determines how many buttons can be clicked. E.g if the text box has a value of 2, then the user can only select two button, a button is selected if the button turns red, it is not selected if it turns or stays white.

The problem is what is happening is that if the value is 1 or above, the user can select all the buttons, in other words if they just keep clicking on buttons then all the buttons would turn red, when what should happen is if the user goes over the value, then an error message appears stating you have went over the limit, please deselect a button if you want to choose another button.

How can I get it so that the number of buttons selected matches the value from the textbox?

code is in jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7WwaK/2/) (for some strange reason it is not letting me click on any button and text box is allowing entry of letters in jsfiddle, even though in my app with the exact code it works fine. Please look at function btnclick (btn) to help you.)

Answer (score 2):

You're resetting the total on each click, so you're not really counting. Move the `currenttotal = 0;` outside the click function (and declare it with `var`).

Secondly, you have really much of the same code. You could also iterate to make the `.className` assignments on the buttons a bit more concise:

```
for(var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) { // iterate over character codes for A to Z
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(i);
    document.getElementById("answer" + letter).className = "answerBtnsOff";
}
```

You could also put the class names in HTML with the `class="answerBtnsOff"` attribute. You could even create the buttons through JavaScript. That would make for some cleaner and more readable code, but of course these optimizations are not necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/7WwaK/3/

(For the jsFiddle to work, you have to select `no wrap (body)` in the left panel, but that's just how jsFiddle inserts the JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right, you should do (IMHO) the following this:

1. Move `var currenttotal = 0;` outside your function. You are resetting it on each click on a button.
2. Edit the currenttotal after the user changes the number of answers. Add therefore the line `currenttotal = document.getElementById('numberAnswerTxt').value();` to the function called `getButtons()`.
3. You could implement the loop that pimvdb suggested to reduce your code (=

Please tell me if this is working.